# Probability of rolling x dice

Tags: probability, functions, dice

How do you calculate the probability of rolling something with x 6-sided dice?

- *Example 1: Rolling exactly one 6 with three 6-sided dice.*
- *Example 2: Rolling exactly two 6s with three 6-sided dice.*
- *Example 3: Rolling exactly five 6s with ten 6-sided dice.*

Also, out of curiosity, what would a function look like if it also had the amount of sides of the die as a variable (so an n-sided die as opposed to a 6-sided one)?

Comment: If $x=3$, your formula $1-(\frac56)^x$ is the probability of rolling one **or more** $6$s.  This does not appear to be the question you asked.  So I think you need to edit the question and make it completely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Done. I was thinking of it as "if there is a 6 in the throw", not as "if there is exactly one 6 in the throw".

Comment: Apparently, editing a question after answers have been posted is considered a [bad murder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inB4esNoNTo). Woops. For this reason, I have posted the new, clarified question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612113/probability-of-rolling-%e2%89%a5-x-with-k-out-of-m-n-sided-dice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B_{n,p}$, the count of successes among $n$ independent trials with identical success rate $p$ follows a **Binomial Distribution**. $$B_{n,p}\sim\mathcal {Binomial}(n,p) \iff \mathsf P(B_{n,p}=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0,..,n\}}$$

This is the count of selections of $k$ from $n$ trials, times $k$ probabilities for successes and $n-k$ probabilities for failure.

If you wish the probability for exactly $1$ six among $3$ rolls of a six sided die, that is :

$$\mathsf P(B_{3,1/6}{=}1)=\dbinom 3 1 \dfrac {1^15^2}{6^3}=\dfrac{25}{72}$$

And such.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the function shouldn't calculate the probability of rolling exactly one 6, but rather the probability of there being a 6 (so rolling one or more 6s).

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment.  I've rollbacked the question since [a question should not be a moving target](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189) according to one of our site mods.

Comment: In any case, the same principle applies.  The probability of rolling *at least one* six is either (a) the sum over, $k$ from $1$ to $6$, of the probabilities for rolling $k$ sixes, or (b) $1$ minus the probability for rolling $0$ sixes.  Whichever you think is easier to calculate (hint: (b)) will give the same answer as the other.$$\mathsf P(B_{3,1/6}\geq 1) ~{=\sum_{k=1}^6 \mathsf P(B_{3,1/6}=k)\\= 1-\mathsf P(B_{3,1/6}= 0)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:  ${3\choose 1}\cdot {\frac 16}\cdot{\frac 56}^2$

Example 2:  ${3\choose 2}\cdot(\frac 16)^2\frac 56$

Example 3:  ${10\choose 5}\cdot(\frac 16)^5(\frac 56)^5$

In general:  ${x\choose k}\cdot(\frac 16)^k(\frac 56)^{x-k})$

For $n$-sided dice, you get:  ${x\choose k}\cdot ({\frac1n})^k \cdot {(\frac {n-1}n})^{x-k}$

For one or more sixes, say, we get: $\sum_{k=1}^x{x\choose k}\cdot \frac{{(n-1)}^{x-k}}{n^x }$

For $2$ or more subtract the probability of getting exactly $1$ six;  for $3$ or more subtract the probabilities of getting exactly $1$ and that of exactly $2$ sixes, etc...

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the function shouldn't calculate the probability of rolling exactly one 6, but rather the probability of there being a 6 (so rolling one or more 6s).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm going to invalidate your response to recent changes of the question by [rolling back the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).

Comment: @GNUSupporter. You're probably right to do so...

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thanks for your comprehension.  You'll probably be able to rollback questions after reaching 2000 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I like starting with choosing the right probability space.  This helps understanding the problem.  In a generalized problem of *rolling $x$ 6s with $N$ $n$-sided dice*:

- the sample space of *a priori* possible outcomes is $\Omega = \{1,\dots,n\}^N$
- ${\cal A} = {\cal P}(\Omega)$ since $|\Omega|=n^N<\infty$
- judge from the question context, the dice is assumed to be fair: $\mathbb{P} = \mathsf{Unif}(\Omega)$
- the event $A$ is *rolling $x$ 6s* is to choose $x$ components to place the outcome *6s* from an $N$-tuple.  For the remaining $N-x$ components, all outcomes are *a priori* possible except *6*.  There are $|A| = \binom{N}{x}(n-1)^{N-x}$

$${\Bbb P}(A) = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|} = \frac{\binom{N}{x}(n-1)^{N-x}}{n^N}$$

We can now solve the three examples with $n=6$.

1. Take $N = 3, x = 1$, ${\Bbb P}(A) = \dfrac{25}{72}$
2. Take $N = 3, x = 2$, ${\Bbb P}(A) = \dfrac{5}{72}$
3. Take $N = 10, x = 5$, ${\Bbb P}(A) = \dfrac{262}{20117}$

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the function shouldn't calculate the probability of rolling exactly one 6, but rather the probability of there being a 6 (so rolling one or more 6s).

Comment: @Biosmosis Such edit renders all existing wrong, and this is *not* accepted on Math.SE.  As you're new here, I refer you to [a question on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189) about changing the question after receiving answers.  You may see [another meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26022/290189) to know more.  As a result, I rollbacked your question to #2.

Comment: I understand. I have edited the question so it's closer to what the answerers interpreted it as.

Comment: @Biosmosis I appreciate your effort to make your question clear.  It'll be even better to do so *before* getting an answer.

Comment: I posted the new, clarified question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612113/probability-of-rolling-%e2%89%a5-x-with-k-out-of-m-n-sided-dice). Thanks for helping me out.