# Probability of rolling ≥ $x$ with $k$ out of $m$ $n$-sided dice

Tags: probability, functions, dice

I previously posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610063/probability-of-rolling-x-dice), but unintentionally omitted some crucial details I only realized after it had already been answered.

As such, my question is this:

How do you calculate the probability of rolling $x$ or more with $k$ out of $m$ dice with $n$ sides?

- *Example 1: Rolling one or more $6$s with three 6-sided dice.*
- *Example 2: Rolling two or more $6$s, $7$s or $8$s with six 8-sided dice.*
- *Example 3: Rolling three or more $7$s, $8$s, $9$s or $10$s with nine 10-sided dice.*

I'm looking for a general function, but thus far have only been able to figure out $f(x)\to1-(\frac56)^x$ for *Example 1*.

While the [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610063/probability-of-rolling-x-dice) of my previous question helped a great deal, any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find expressions by means of binomial distribution (as made clear in the answer to your former question). Have you tried out? For e.g. example 2 there is a probability of $\frac38$ on a success and there are $6$ tries. So the parameters are $n=6$ and $p=\frac38$, and to be found is $P(X\geq2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)$.

Comment: Can you expand on that, @drhab? I'm not sure how to calculate that in practice, or how to apply it to the other examples in a generalized fasion.

Comment: If I interpreted your question correctly then in example 1 we have $x=1$, $k=3$ and $n=6$. In example 2 we have $x=2$, $k=6$ and $n=8$. Is that correct? I cannot find any interpretation of $m$ though.

Comment: In my question, $k$ represents the minimum amount of successes, while $m$ represents the total amount of dice. As such, for *Example 1*, $k=1$ while $m=3$, $x=6$ and $n=6$. For *Example 2*, $k=2$, $m=6$, $x=6$ and $n=8$. It's worth noting $x$ represents the threshold for success, where everything below (so 1 to 5 for *Example 2*) is a failure.

Comment: "...rolling  $x$ or more.." together with "..rolling one or more.." in example 1 makes it look that $x=1$ there.